# Kendo Datasource "e is undefined" error

Tags: kendo-ui, datasource

in Telerik Kendo UI 2016 Q2 I want to create datasource:

```
var dat1 = '{"items":[{ name: "Pork", category: "Food", subcategory: "Meat" },{ name: "Pepper", category: "Food", subcategory: "Vegetables" },{ name: "Beef", category: "Food", subcategory: "Meat" }]}';
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: dat1,
    dataType: "json",
    schema: {
        data: "items"
    }
});
dataSource.fetch(function () {
});
```

But I got this error in firefox/firebug

TypeError: e is undefined

I know erro is for `"schema: {data:"items"}"`

also change dataType to jsonp and have same error.

Comment: Does this occur on fetch? Try adding model for the data source or try using `datasource.read()`

Comment: Why are you setting dat1 to a string?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
schema: {
data: function(response) {
  return response.items; }
}
```

And then watch in debugger what caused that error

Also dat1 is a string, use `JSON.parse` to create JSON from it